# System process high idle CPU usage ( 30 - 40 percent )

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, windows-11-preview

I am using windows 11 canary build, this issue is since windows 10, the system process uses half of my CPU as soon as I connect my pc to the internet, it makes the fan whirr fast and gaming performance is degraded a lot.
I can't seem to pinpoint the problem, I tried doing these -  clean boot and disabling SuperFetch.
It turns out that the system process does not take more than 1 percent of my CPU in safe mode with networking. Please help me pinpoint the problem.

Comment: You're running an insider preview version of Windows. Issues with such builds are to be expected as they are nowhere near finalized, and should be reported through [Feedback Hub](https://aka.ms/WIPFeedbackHub) or other resources listed in the [Win insider program page](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/about-windows-insider-program). If you want a stable Windows, use an official released desktop version.

Comment: for those who are saying i am using windows 11 insider, I mentioned that this issue is persisting from windows 10